# Filter out records from 3D array based on the values in column of 2D array

Tags: numpy, filter, filtering

I have a 3D array of shapes (3, 5, 5) as per below. I want to filter out all records (rows) from constituent 2D arrays where col of index 0 is nan.

I have tried below but it returns back a 2D array instead of a desired 3D array.

```
arr[ np.where(arr[:, :, 0] != np.nan)]
```

Can you please suggest the correct way of achieving the stated objective?

Thank you!

```
[[[1. 0. 0.10. 0.]
  [2. 0. 0. 9. 0.]
  [nan. 0. 0. 8. 0.]
  [4. 0. 0. 7. 0.]
  [nan. 0. 0. 6. 0.]]
 [[1. 0. 0. 199. 0.]
  [2. 0. 0. 198. 0.]
  [3. 0. 0. 196. 0.]
  [nan. 0. 0. 190. 0.]
  [nan. 0. 0. 160. 0.]]
 [[1. 0. 0. 999. 0.]
  [2. 0. 0. 870. 0.]
  [nan. 0. 0. 270. 0.]
  [nan. 0. 0. 100. 0.]
  [nan. 0. 0. 80. 0.]]]
```

Comment: In your example you have 3 of 2D arrays. After na filtering the shape of the first array (3, 5); shape of the second one (3, 5); the shape of the third is (2, 5). So how do you expect to stack 3 arrays with different shapes into one 3D array?

Comment: Hi @u1234x1234, that is exactly the challenge. I was thinking alongside of dirty or non-homogenous arrays. I could put such array together by looping through 3d array, but that is very heavy operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use a list of 2D arrays as a result because after `na` filtering the shapes of inner the 2D arrays will be different so they can not be stacked together into a 3D array.

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
 [[1., 0., 0., 10., 0.],
  [2., 0., 0., 9., 0.],
  [np.nan, 0., 0., 8., 0.],
  [4., 0., 0., 7., 0.],
  [np.nan, 0., 0., 6., 0.]],
 [[1., 0., 0., 199., 0.],
  [2., 0., 0., 198., 0.],
  [3., 0., 0., 196., 0.],
  [np.nan, 0., 0., 190., 0.],
  [np.nan, 0., 0., 160., 0.]],
 [[1., 0., 0., 999., 0.],
  [2., 0., 0., 870., 0.],
  [np.nan, 0., 0., 270., 0.],
  [np.nan, 0., 0., 100., 0.],
  [np.nan, 0., 0., 80., 0.]]],
)

row_masks = np.isnan(arr[:, :, 0])
result = [arr2d[~row_mask] for arr2d, row_mask in zip(arr, row_masks)]
```

Result:

```
[array([[ 1.,  0.,  0., 10.,  0.],
        [ 2.,  0.,  0.,  9.,  0.],
        [ 4.,  0.,  0.,  7.,  0.]])
 array([[  1.,   0.,   0., 199.,   0.],
        [  2.,   0.,   0., 198.,   0.],
        [  3.,   0.,   0., 196.,   0.]])
 array([[  1.,   0.,   0., 999.,   0.],
        [  2.,   0.,   0., 870.,   0.]])]
```

Comment: Hi @u1234x1234, this has worked. Thank you.